# What's exactly inside the attribute 'Pars' in apVar of the lme object in R

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix

In [this example](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-calculate-standard-errors-for-variance-components-from-mixed-models/):
what is the third term in `attr(,"Pars")` within the `apVar` of the `lme` object (`model.c$apVar` in this example)? I know it is related to the correlation of the two random effects, but how is this calculated? How can I calculate this manually from the correlation in the output of `VarCorr(model.c)`?